# Grouping roads based on existing condition and AADT? (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, buffer, road, proximity, grouping

For **QGIS** software, I have municipality service agreement roads and an end-plan to group the roads based on close proximity (roads and communities close together or close to each other and on the same side of the main road), with similar need for re-pavement or maintenance - i.e. similar current conditions.... The road shapefile has attributes for roadside development score, AADT (Annual Average Daily Traffic) score, pavement priority points (scores), existing road surface, and existing road condition. I would like to find a way to group the roads based on priority for development/maintenance, such as roads in the worst condition that have the highest traffic and are currently most developed, to roads that need least amounts of development/maintenance. I believe I am able to use the pavement priority score as my main symbology type since this ties in both the roadside development score and AADT, OR it is possible for me to symbolize based on existing condition.

Any ideas of how I could go about this using QGIS?

I know that a buffer would be a good geoprocessing tool to use and will likely be in my end-product... However, I have limited experience in this area, and I am having a hard time finding a good starting point.

Answer (score 3):

I've outlined several options below.  You could try rules based rendering to define the different categories you want to show.  For example:

- pavement priority = 1 and condition = 'poor'
- pavement priority = 2 and condition = 'poor'
- pavement priority = 1 and condition = 'ok'
- pavement priority = 2 and condition = 'ok'
- pavement priority = 1 and condition = 'good'
- pavement priority = 2 and condition = 'good'

Or you could use the rules above to create a new field (e.g. priority_score) in your dataset and populate it with an overall score derived from the combined fields:

```
CASE 
  WHEN pavement priority = 1 and condition = 'poor' THEN 1
  WHEN pavement priority = 2 and condition = 'poor' THEN 2
  WHEN pavement priority = 1 and condition = 'ok' THEN 3
  WHEN pavement priority = 2 and condition = 'ok' THEN 4
  WHEN pavement priority = 1 and condition = 'good' THEN 5
  WHEN pavement priority = 2 and condition = 'good' THEN 6
  ELSE 0
END
```

Obviously you could add more conditions to the rules.  If you use the **List Unique Values** tool in QGIS Vector > Analysis Tools you can get the values for each field you need.

Or you could try some of the techniques outlined in [this post](http://www.joshuastevens.net/cartography/make-a-bivariate-choropleth-map/) to show the combination of two variables.

Or you could duplicate the layer on the canvas as many times as there are fields in your data and then display each layer using a different field and and blend the layers together - darker areas are high priority, lighter areas lower.

Whichever way you go about it you need to know your data and what each score means.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply and additional link. I will look into this today and try it out, as it seems like a good path to take for tackling both important variables. I will report back shortly!